# CMake find_file not finding file

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml-cpp

Trying to load `yaml-cpp` in my project

```
add_executable(abhi src.cpp)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "absolute_path_of_directory")
find_path(yaml-cpp_INCLUDE_DIRS yaml-cpp/yaml.h NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
target_include_directories(abhi yaml-cpp_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

When I m removing `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` then it is finding the correct path in `/usr/local/include`, but if my move search to specific directory by setting `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` and cmake using `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` it is not finding the path to file

----UPDATE-----
It was a silly mistake from my side I was searching for `yaml-cpp/yaml.h` inside `abs_path/yaml-cpp` but the search should be in in the path `abs_path/` instead.Thank you for taking your time and helping me out :)

Comment: Have you tried [`--debug-find`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html) mode? And the minimal example that reproduces the problem also would be nice to have.

Comment: this thing is not working so I tried `--trace` but I found nothing useful there

Comment: Please provide the minimal project, so somebody could try to build it. And what do you mean _not working_? Did you use the latest CMake?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` is meant to be set as a *cache* variable, at the `cmake` command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=“absolute_path_of_directory”
```

or as an environment variable.

Comment: You may have to clear your CMake cache and run it from scratch. I recommend reading through the documentation for `find_path` to see the complete search procedure.

Comment: The mentioned variable could be used in `CMakeLists.txt` as well, it doesn't need to be the cache variable.